# Automatically prefix row group names of a `gt` table

Tags: r, gt

I have the following `gt` table that has two groups:

```r
library(gt)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

iris[c(1:2, 51:52), ] |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  gt()
```

[image]

I'd like to prefix the title of each group with "Panel XX" where "XX" is the group number, so that the new names of the groups become "Panel 1: setosa" and "Panel 2: versicolor". As far as I can see, I could do it manually with `tab_row_group()` but I'm looking for an automated way (meaning without hardcoding the group values in the original dataset or counting the groups myself).

Is it possible to do so?

---

**Edit**: @jpsmith's answer works with the simple example in my post, but the reason I didn't want to modify the values in the original dataset is because it makes it annoying to use `gt::cells_row_groups()` in the same call:

```r
iris[c(1:2, 51:52), ] |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  mutate(Species = paste0("Panel ", cur_group_id(), ": ", Species)) |>
  gt() |> 
  tab_footnote(
    "a footnote",
    locations = cells_row_groups(groups = "setosa")
  )

Error in `resolver_stop_on_character()`:
! The following row group(s) do not exist in the data: setosa.
```

Comment: Re your edit, It's not as flexible as using names, but you can use indices to specify the groups, e.g., `groups = 1`.

Comment: That's not ideal because if the order in the original dataset changes later then the location will be wrong. But it's a nice workaround for now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this can't be done in a convenient way through package functions, one way is to overwrite the labels in the gt object itself.  This way the row group ID is unchanged so it can still be used by name. I don't think this will break anything, but I'm not making any guarantees.

```
library(gt)

my_gt <- iris[c(1:2, 51:52), ] |> 
    group_by(Species) |>
    gt() 

labs <- unlist(my_gt$`_stub_df`$group_label)

# Stored in a list column
my_gt$`_stub_df`$group_label <- as.list(paste0("Panel ", match(labs, unique(labs)), ": ", labs))


my_gt |>
  tab_footnote(
    "a footnote",
    locations = cells_row_groups(groups = "setosa")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could get this by simply mutating the `Species` with `paste0` after creating a temporary group ID variable using `cur_group_id()`:

```
# Thanks to @Ritchie Sacramento for the improved code

iris[c(1:2, 51:52), ] |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  mutate(Species = paste0("Panel ", cur_group_id(), ": ", Species)) |>
  gt::gt()
```

[image]

If you wanted to add a footnote with `cell_row_groups`, you could indicate by group number:

```
iris[c(1:2, 51:52), ] |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  mutate(Species = paste0("Panel ", cur_group_id(), ": ", Species)) |>
  gt() |> 
  tab_footnote(
    "a footnote",
    locations = cells_row_groups(groups = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: @RitchieSacramento genius! I edited to include the improved code

Comment: That indeed works but it would be great to have different numbering styles (A, B, C or I, II, III instead of Panel 1, 2, 3 for example), but that's maybe for another question

Comment: @bretauv - if you want roman numerals, use `as.roman(cur_group_id())`, if you want letters, use `LETTERS[cur_group_id()]` etc.

Comment: @jpsmith actually this answer makes it hard to use `gt::cells_row_groups()`, I updated my post

Comment: @bretauv - I see - I've added a workaround to add a footnote that may be convenient, in which you just specify the group by panel number